# Remove trailing 0 from ajax-response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know there is also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com however I think this is probablynot a wordpress specific question:

```
$.get(
    ajax.url, 
    {
        'action': 'ajax',
    }, 
    function( response, status, xhr ) {
        $('ul.event-items').append(response);
        }
);
```

I'm calling a regular wordpress function that has no 0 in it or whatsoever.

However after every ajax-request I get a trailing zero appended to my document.

How can I fix this? I tried using `die();` in my function however the rest of my script will not get rendered in that case.

Is there an easy JS-fix like subsrting() to remove the trailing 0 from my html response?

Kind regards,
Matt

Comment: can you show the string? also try to find out any unwanted echo statements

Comment: You could use a conditional  `js substr()` and check if the last character is '0' and lop it off it is.  I'd wanna know where its coming from though, cause it might turn into something else later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
$('ul.event-items').append(response.substr(response.length-1, 1) === '0'? response.substr(0, response.length-1) : response);
```

Answer (score 10):

The documentation uses `wp_die()` at the end of the php function to prevent the 0 (and presumably other problems too).

```
"wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response"
```

[Link to docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: If you are working with WordPress, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

```
Example

Extract characters from a string:

var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1,4);
The result of res will be:

ell
```